# Why can't Python parse this JSON data?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have this JSON in a file:

```json
{
    "maps": [
        {
            "id": "blabla",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "blabla",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        }
    ],
    "masks": [
        "id": "valore"
    ],
    "om_points": "value",
    "parameters": [
        "id": "valore"
    ]
}
```

I wrote this script to print all of the JSON data:

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

pprint(data)
```

This program raises an exception, though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 13 column 13 (char 213)
```

How can I parse the JSON and extract its values?

Comment: This question's status was discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381492/1394393). Community consensus was that this question was "good enough" to be left open after substantial edits. Please open a new discussion if you feel something has changed since that discussion.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419062) for a second time.

Answer (score 2193, accepted):

Your data is not valid [JSON](https://www.json.org/) format. You have `[]` when you should have `{}` for the `"masks"` and `"parameters"` elements:

- `[]` are for JSON arrays, which are called `list` in Python
- `{}` are for JSON objects, which are called `dict` in Python

Here's how your JSON file should look:

```json
{
    "maps": [
        {
            "id": "blabla",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "blabla",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        }
    ],
    "masks": {
        "id": "valore"
    },
    "om_points": "value",
    "parameters": {
        "id": "valore"
    }
}
```

Then you can use your code:

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

pprint(data)
```

With data, you can now also find values like so:

```py
data["maps"][0]["id"]
data["masks"]["id"]
data["om_points"]
```

Try those out and see if it starts to make sense.

Comment: serialized data is wrapped with [] , and when you read it in you need f.read(), that is if you use the standard.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. i'm getting a unicode symbol while printing it. (eg u'valore' ). How to prevent it?

Comment: Nice but python adds a `u'` before each key. Any idea why?

Comment: That is why your text is type unicode not string. Most time it is better to have text in unicode for german umlauts and for sharing text results with other modules/programs etc. . So you're good!

Comment: How to know size of the maps array to control index in this example?data["maps"][0]["id"] - Here 0 hard coded.

Comment: isn't there a resource leak because the handle to `data.json` is never closed?

Comment: In python 3, my json file is an array [] of jsons, it's called valid json by online checkers, and with these commands it loaded perfectly. Perhaps the definitions have changed circa 2018?

Comment: @nikhilvj json doesn't need to have `{}` at the root level. It can start with an array at the root level (`[]`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27415238/3299397 need this piece for it to work.

Comment: What exception will be thrown if the with call fails? Should this be wrapped in a try catch?

Comment: @JustinPeel is there any chance that the order of the elements that are in the array (value of maps) will be changed. For example storing it into a data store (elastic search or any database) and then getting it back from there.

Answer (score 322):

Your `data.json` should look like this:

```
{
 "maps":[
         {"id":"blabla","iscategorical":"0"},
         {"id":"blabla","iscategorical":"0"}
        ],
"masks":
         {"id":"valore"},
"om_points":"value",
"parameters":
         {"id":"valore"}
}
```

Your code should be:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data)
```

Note that this only works in Python 2.6 and up, as it depends upon the [`with`-statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). In Python 2.5 use `from __future__ import with_statement`, in Python <= 2.4, see [Justin Peel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835672/906658), which this answer is based upon.

You can now also access single values like this:

```
data["maps"][0]["id"]  # will return 'blabla'
data["masks"]["id"]    # will return 'valore'
data["om_points"]      # will return 'value'
```

Comment: Referring to 2.6 documentation (https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/io.html), opening a file in the "with" context will automatically close the file.

Comment: @SteveS. Yes, but not before the context is left. `pprint`ing in the `with`-context keeps the `data_file` open longer.

Comment: Is there a way to access like data.om_points or data.masks.id?

Comment: This works except when I try to use a numbered index like `data["maps"][0]["id"]`  I see error: `KeyError: 0`

Comment: @GayanPathirage you access it like `data["om_points"]` , `data["masks"]["id"]`. The idea is you can reach any level in a dictionary  by specifying the 'key paths'. If you get a `KeyError` exception it means the key doesn't exist in the path. Look out for typos or check the structure of your dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go with modified `data.json` file:

```json
{
    "maps": [
        {
            "id": "blabla",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "blabla",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        }
    ],
    "masks": [{
        "id": "valore"
    }],
    "om_points": "value",
    "parameters": [{
        "id": "valore"
    }]
}
```

You can call or print data on console by using below lines:

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data_item = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data_item)
```

Expected output for `print(data_item['parameters'][0]['id'])`:

```
{'maps': [{'id': 'blabla', 'iscategorical': '0'},
          {'id': 'blabla', 'iscategorical': '0'}],
 'masks': [{'id': 'valore'}],
 'om_points': 'value',
 'parameters': [{'id': 'valore'}]}
```

Expected output for `print(data_item['parameters'][0]['id'])`:

```
valore
```

Comment: If we would like add a column to count how many observations does "maps" have, how could we write this function?